# Sprintf Does not work properly

Tags: xc8

Hello I am working on Pic18f46k22 with xc8 compiler.sprintf Function does not work properly.
My code is:

```
    const char *DATA[4] = {"xxxxxx","yyyyyy","zzzzzz","aaaa"}
    unsigned char Data1=2;
    unsigned char Data2=3;
    char L1Buffer[6];
    char L2Buffer[6];
    char TotalBuffer[20];


    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){L1Buffer[i]=0;L2Buffer[i]=0;}
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){TotalBuffer[i]=0;}

    sprintf (L1Buffer,"%s", DATA[Data1]);
    sprintf (L2Buffer,"%s%d", DATA[Data2],Data2);
    sprintf(TotalBuffer,"L1:%s L2:%s",L1Buffer,L2Buffer);

    Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
    printf("%s",TotalBuffer);

    Lcd_Set_Cursor(3,1);
    printf("%s",L2Buffer);
```

Output :

```
L1:zzzzzzaaaa3 L2:aa
aaaa3
```

Expected output :

```
L1:zzzzzz L2:aaaa3
aaaa3
```

Comment: Don't forget to allocate space for `'\0'` character. C strings are null terminated!

Comment: I tried some methods But I am fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting 7 characters (six `'z'`s + one `'\0'`) into six character array. You need to take space for null terminator into account.

You need to declare `L1Buffer` to hold 7 characters:

```
unsigned char L1Buffer[7];
```

In your case, `L1Buffer` and `L2Buffer` are placed adjacent in memory. Writing "zzzzzz" into `L1Buffer` places six `'z'`s in `L1Buffer` and `'\0'` into `L2Buffer[0]`, as it happens to be located right next to it:

```
 z z z z z z\0 . . . . .
`-L1Buffer-'`-L2Buffer-'
```

Then, `L2Buffer` is overwritten:

```
 z z z z z z a a a a 3\0
`-L1Buffer-'`-L2Buffer-'
```

Note there's no terminator after `'z'`s, so `sprintf(TotalBuffer,"L1:%s L2:%s",L1Buffer,L2Buffer);` takes `L1Buffer` values until it encounters nul lterminator at the end of `L2Buffer`. That's why you get `zzzzzzaaaa3`.